# New tag proposal: APA-style

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

The American Psychological Association (APA) publishes its *Publication Manual*, now in its sixth edition, documenting (among other things) the [APA Style](http://www.apastyle.org), a citation and referencing style. APA Style is pretty common. It is pretty much the only style used in psychology journals, but is also used in other fields. There are [BibTeX packages on CRAN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2628/22201) to implement it.

We have quite a few [questions related to APA style](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22APA+Style%22+is%3Aquestion).

I propose creating a new tag [apa-style](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apa-style) and retagging these questions (except for [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/24377/4140) and [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10963/4140)) unless there are objections.

Thoughts?

Comment: To the downvoter: was the downvote because you disagreed with the idea or because you thought it was a bad question?  I think a question can be good even if the answer is "no"

Comment: @jakebeal [voting on meta is different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) and down votes often me "no" even if it is a good question.

Comment: @StrongBad Thanks: Somehow, I had never realized that the help menu was different in meta...

Comment: This has been open for five days, with no activity for the last three. I'll ask the mods to tag this [tag:status-declined]. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I don't really think we need a separate tag for each [citation-style](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-style). (Let the votes on this answer indicate what everyone else thinks...)

Comment: APA style is a lot more than just a citation style. There are at most a few other style guides that are as comprehensive (e.g., Chicago and Modern Language Association). That said, I am not sure the tag is needed.

Comment: @StrongBad We also have [tag:writing-style] and [tag:graphics] to cover other style issues. (Although all but 2 of the questions in Stephan's query are about citation)

Comment: I think [tag:citation-style] is enough but cannot we make the proposed [tag:apa-style] a synonym to it? Just like what we have for [tag:gender] tag and its synonyms?

Answer (score -1):

What about a [style-manuals](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-manuals) tag to cover things like APA, MLA, and the others, where the question is about things that go beyond citations?

Answer (score -2):

APA style is *so* obnoxiously comprehensive (and generally obnoxious and different from other styles) that I think it's reasonable to have its own tag.